# How to get latest record weekly within an SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to export the latest records from SQL Server 2005 database once weekly. This is my table:

```
agent_name  date          ID
ALEX        2015-05-25    13
ALEX        2015-05-22    13
ALICE       2015-05-24    10
ALICE       2015-05-26    10
```

How to create output table should like this:

```
agent_name  date          ID
ALEX        2015-05-25    13
ALICE       2015-05-26    10
```

My SQL script:

```
SELECT a.agent_name,  
       a.date, 
       a.ID 
FROM Payment a 
INNER JOIN agentmaster b ON a.ID = b.ID2 
WHERE b.agent ='Y'
AND a.date >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want latest rows for each `ID` and `agent_name` use this:

```
SELECT a.agent_name,  
       MAX(a.[date]) [date], 
       a.ID
FROM Payment a 
GROUP BY
    a.agent_name,  
    a.ID
```

---

If you want to have latest rows in each week use this:

```
SELECT a.agent_name,  
       a.date, 
       a.ID
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(WEEK, [date]) ORDER BY [date] DESC) seq
      FROM Payment ) a 
WHERE
    seq = 1
```

---

If you want latest rows for each `ID` and `agent_name` at each week use this:

```
;WITH p AS (
    /* add your query here */
)
SELECT a.agent_name,  
       a.date, 
       a.ID
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY agent_name, ID, DATEPART(WEEK, [date]) ORDER BY [date] DESC) seq
      FROM p ) a 
WHERE
    seq = 1
```

Comment: I want latest rows for each ID and agent_name, but i'm using inner join. My script `SELECT a.agent_name,  
       a.date, 
       a.ID 
FROM Payment a 
INNER JOIN agentmaster b ON a.ID = b.ID2 
WHERE b.agent ='Y'
AND a.date >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())`

Comment: @alvin you can use `WITH` and add your joined query in it ;).

Answer (score 1):

This will return records from the first day of the current week to the last day of the current week

```
   SELECT a.agent_name  
          ,a.date 
          ,a.ID 
   FROM Payment a INNER JOIN agentmaster b 
        ON a.ID = b.ID2 
   WHERE b.agent ='Y' AND 
         (a.date BETWEEN 
                 DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GetDate()),0) AND
                 DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()),6))
```

Comment: How does it return ***latest***?

Comment: It returns records from the first day of the week to the last day of the week

Comment: Your code seems like get all the data in the week. How to get only last day of the week (latest record)

Comment: @alvin you should have fixed your question to express the fact that you need the latest record. You are returning two records in your example, in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT ID, Agent_Name, MAX(Date) Max_Date
FROM AgentMaster
GROUP BY Agent_Name, ID
```

If you want to add the date filter then add the where condition

```
date >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I think this will return the most recent record whereas the output example in the question shows two records.

Comment: Not working, why                                                                                `SELECT a.agent_name,  
       MAX(a.date), 
       a.ID 
FROM Payment a 
INNER JOIN agentmaster b ON a.ID = b.ID2 
WHERE b.agent ='Y'
AND a.date >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I make a table in a `CTE` and defines the first day of week within a period. And then make a `JOIN` between the first day of weeks and our actual query

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(agent_name VARCHAR(10) ,[date] date, Id INT)

INSERT @tbl
SELECT 'ALEX'  ,      '2015-05-25'  ,  13 UNION
SELECT 'ALEX'  ,      '2015-05-22'  ,  13 UNION
SELECT 'ALICE' ,      '2015-05-24'  ,  10 UNION
SELECT 'ALICE' ,      '2015-05-26'  ,  10

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

**Query**

```
-- This period can be changed
DECLARE @StartDate date = '01/01/2015'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '01/01/2016'

;WITH Numbers (Number)
AS
(
  SELECT number
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE [type] = 'P'
 )
,firstDayOfWeek (fWDate)
AS
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, @StartDate)
  FROM Numbers AS n
  WHERE n.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
  AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, @StartDate)) = 1 --Defines first day of week
 )
SELECT t.agent_name, Max(t.date) AS [date], t.Id
FROM @tbl AS t
INNER JOIN firstDayOfWeek AS fw ON t.date >= fw.fWDate
AND t.[date] < DATEADD(DAY, 7, fw.fWDate)
GROUP BY t.Id, t.agent_name
```